# iOS11 How to change the height navigationbar

Tags: height, navigationbar

iOS10 before

[image: iOS10 before]

iOS11 after

[image: iOS11 after]

Now in iOS 11, the sizeThatFits method is not called from UINavigationBar subclasses.